# AlertDIalog with two EditText fields

Tags: android, layout, dialog, android-edittext

I am trying to create custom AlertDialog with two EditText fields for input. Here is the code:

```
void newItemInput(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null));

    builder.setTitle("");
    builder.setMessage("");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            EditText item_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            EditText item_price =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.item_price);

            String text = item_name.getText().toString();
            String text_price = item_price.getText().toString();
            int price = Integer.parseInt(text_price);

            // Do something with value!
            products.add(new Product(text, price, R.drawable.unread, false));

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

`AlertDialog` shows up and I can input data. But when I press OK, while passing text and price as arguments to `products.add(new Product(text, price, R.drawable.unread, false))`, app crashes down.
Here is the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/item_price"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please let me know, what am I doing wrong. When I do not use custom Dialog and use only one text field it works fine. But I need two fields, and I am assuming that this crash because of `LayoutInflater`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Firstly**, in the future, when you receive LogCat errors, please post them.

**Best solution** is to cast the dialog to an `AlertDialog`, then use that.

```
AlertDialog aDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog; // This will ONLY work if (dialog instanceof AlertDialog)
EditText item_name = (EditText) aDialog.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
EditText item_price =(EditText) aDialog.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
```

Alternatively, **if the above doesn't work**, you can save the `View` you give to the builder, then use that instead.

Like so, using a `final` modifier to access within the `OnClickListener`:

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);
builder.setView(v);
```

Then, access `v.findViewById` within the `OnClickListener` to find the views.

Comment: no crash but no result. arguments don't reach products.add(new Product(text, price, R.drawable.unread, false));

Comment: There is no reason `products.add` wouldn't execute if `aDialog.findViewById` did, as there is nothing in between that would block it. How are you checking the result? Try adding a log output, or something.

Comment: your best solution works but in a strange way. it provides arguments after second time input. Like I have inputed name and price it did not show up and when I have inputed other values second time here comes previous and the new one.

Comment: only previous, next try the one before, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but maybe try using `setText("")` on the `EditText`s to erase their values? You shouldn't be reusing the same dialog once you've built it.

Comment: You are probably right. I am using dialog second time and the previous entry shows up. Is there possiblity to release dialog and use it again and again?

Comment: Actually I thought that Dialog would be alternative to EditText for input of small String and int data. I am a new one with Android. Please explain if I can use Dialog like this.

Comment: It fits very well to my needs except this strange behaviour.

Comment: You're using a dialog now, yes, which contains `EditText`s. For an input dialog, this is desirable. I struggle to see why the previous data would appear, assuming you are calling `newItemInput()` a second time. It would be a new builder, a new view, and a new dialog.

Comment: I have onClick method and it simply calls newItemInput.

Comment: the update goes to ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

Comment: No, I'm not sure. But comments are not for solving new problems. Mark this one as solved (the green checkbox beside the answer), then start a new question.

Comment: Just to say that I have managed it, forgot to notifyDataSetChanged inside onClick.

Answer (score 0):

Where AlertDialog alertDialog = (AletrDialog)dialog;

```
EditText item_name = (EditText)**alertDialog **.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

EditText item_price =(EditText)**alertDialog **.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
```

you have to find the views in a dialog in this way.

As Eric Mentioned the dialog should get typecasted to AlertDialog

Comment: This will not work. `DialogInterface` has no `findViewById` method.